# Data-based MapReduce issue on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, timezone, timestamp

I am using MapReduce in MongoDB to aggregate on a day-level basis. On the map code, I have the following snippet to obtain the day of the year:

```
var day = Date.UTC(this.time.getFullYear(), this.time.getMonth(), this.time.getDate(), 1, 0, 0);
```

And in most of the cases, it works well. However, apparently there is a timezone issue, which forces timestamps to be moved to the previous date. For instance, documents obtained from the result of this query:

```
{'time' : {'$gte' : new Date(2014, 0, 1, 0), '$lt' : new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9)}}
```

End up being a 2013-12-31 17:00:00.000Z and the ones queried with:

```
{'time' : {'$gte' : new Date(2014, 0, 1, 9), '$lt' : new Date(2014, 0, 1, 23)}}
```

end up being 2014-01-01 17:00:00.000Z. How can I control this?

Comment: Whose "day" is it? The person who is querying? The person who stored the data? The person whom the data is about?  Which of these are you aggregating on?  If you aggregate by UTC - then you are *probably* not achieving *any* of these.  Keep in mind that due to the Earth rotating, and use of time zones, everyone has a different concept of what a "day" is.  And to top it off, not all "days" are 24 hours long, due to daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

Be consistent about how you are constructing the dates. [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) gives the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. The [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) constructor returns a Date object based on your local system settings for timezone. That is the root problem. There's a bit too much missing from the code for me to feel confident filling in what the correct statements are, but you should be able to do it.